# Function regularity and Fourier coefficients regularity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $e_k$ be a complete orthonormal basis of $L^2([a,b])$ (for example, $[a,b]=[0,1]$, and the basis is the shifted Legendre polynomials, but I hope the answer to my question is not basis dependent or $[0,1]$ dependent).

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. We know that $\{a_n\} \in l^2(\mathbb N) \iff \exists f \in L^2([a,b])$ such that $a_n = \langle f, e_n \rangle_{L^2}$, see [Necessary and sufficient condition for a sequence of real numbers to be Fourier coefficients of some function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478022/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-a-sequence-of-real-numbers-to-be-fourier)

Now what subset of $l^2(\mathbb N)$ for the Fourier coefficients we would get if we added regularity on the function $f$ in the above equivalence ?

For example, $f$ is non-decreasing ? Or continuous ? Or continuous and non-decreasing at the same time ? Do we get better than square summability of the Fourier coefficients ? Or maybe the Fourier coefficients become a non-decreasing sequence (in the sense that they can be arranged in a non-decreasing way) ?

Comment: As a general fact, regularity in the primary space translates to decay in Fourier space and vice versa. For example, if you have that $f,f',f'',\ldots, f^{(k)} \in L^2[a,b]$, then you will have that $n^ka_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I was thinking about weaker regularities like described in my question

Comment: The answer clearly does depend on what basis you're using. (For  example, if the basis functions are not even continuous you wouldn't expect some simple condition on the coefficients to give regularity for $f$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I see, clearly I spoke much too quickly and flippantly. I will delete my above comment to remove the incorrect information. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: If you can provide a solution for the shifted Legendre polynomials on [0,1], I would be satisfied.